# How to properly mock class modules in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm utilizing this `amplitude` module that requires I instantiate a class first and then uses an instance method. The code is as follows:

```
var Amplitude = require('amplitude');
const amplitude = new Amplitude(process.env.amplitudeApiKey);
```

I then later call `await amplitude.track({something: 'here'})` and want to mock it so that the external library isn't called and that I can verify the arguments. The fact that I have to initialize a class is throwing me off with the mocks.

I tried using a `__mocks__` folder but Typescript suggested the automocking that's turned one. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to mock this scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: "Typescript suggested the automocking that's turned one" can you clarify or rephrase this?

Comment: Turned on. Basically it made the suggestion to use auto mocking but as far I can tell, network requests are still being attempted

Comment: Does that mean you've enabled [automocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#automock-boolean) in your jest configuration?

Comment: Don’t think I have but I read it’s now turned on by default

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using the approach [documented on the Jest website](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks)

```
const Amplitude = require('amplitude');
jest.mock('amplitude');

test('#trackInAmplitude calls the amplitude track event', async () => {
  // Put the code here that calls my `track method`
  const mockAmplitude = Amplitude.mock.instances[0];
  expect(mockAmplitude.track.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('argument body');
});
```